# GAE filter entity key (Golang)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, go

I want to use look like

```
datastore.NewQuery("Article").Filter("ID =", id)
```

to get entity key.

How do this?

Sorry for my poor English. Thanks!

Comment: Can you expand on your example, perhaps in pseudo-code? What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never tried Go but I'll give it a shot:

```
k := datastore.NewKey(c, "Activity", "", id, nil)
q := datastore.NewQuery("Article").Filter("__key__ =", k)
```

Where `c` is your `appengine.Context`

Answer (score 11):

What about these solution, these way you dont need a query, neither an iterator is more direct way of solving the problem.

```
var article Article
k := datastore.NewKey(c, "Article", "", usrr.User, nil)
q := datastore.Get(c,k,&article)
```

What did you think?

Comment: this is definitely the correct way to do, if you get the key, you could get the entity directly instead of making a query